# Does reducing a NP Hard problem to a NP problem make that NP hard problem a NP Complete problem?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, np, decision-problem

I was asked a question in my algorithms exam which had this as the core question after simplifying. I had written that it would be NP-Hard but I got it wrong my professor is saying that it would be NP-Complete.

Kindly help me resolve my doubt.

Comment: By reducing an NP-hard problem to any problem in NP, you show that the problem is in NP. It follows that it is complete for NP.

Comment: Thanks for you answer could you please check a question which I had posted with full context. The link is below: [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145398/find-the-class-of-the-problem-pp1-and-pp2-using-the-information-given-below]

Answer (score 3):

A problem that is both NP hard and in NP is NP-complete.

On the other hand, after reading your question I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I have posted a question with full context. Please check it once in the link below:                   https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145398/find-the-class-of-the-problem-pp1-and-pp2-using-the-information-given-below